# Populating form components from database using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to populate form components(either select,checkbox) from database. The fields of the form depend on each other, i.e I need to populate a component based on user selection on the previous component. To do that, I am using onchange method, from which I raise a AJAX request for the data that need to populate the next tag. Right now, I am returning the string(HTML data) from the controller in backend and setting the corresponding id's innerHTML to these string. I am curious, whether the approach is correct way or should I take the json as the output from AJAX call and generate the HTML in js and then set the innerHTML value to the corresponding id. I am using JSP as View.

Answer (score 1):

i think building the json and building up the components in the page side is safer becuse it makes your business login separate from the view. If it is required to construct a dynamic table without a POJO then there is no other go you have to use the html string data as the output of ajax

Comment: yes..it's not a POJO, if it is a POJO, I would have used JSP to construct the HTML tags dynamically. I am not so comfortable with json, I will try that approach.is storing the json object retrieved from AJAX call into a Global javascript variable and reusing it in different functions a good practice ?